# Why is different end location returned for same destination?

Tags: google-directions-api

I'm using the Google Directions API to find driving time (duration) for several routes using lat/long for origin and destination. For some destinations, I receive different values in the end_location element in the response json depending on the origin of the trip. Why is that?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that would replicate the issue?

Comment: Using the two requests below, which have the same destination location, I receive different end locations.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=driving&origin=57.8043814355003,12.0506500319515&destination=57.7130994553088,11.9909085683375&arrival_time=1548054000&key=*

"end_location": { "lat": 57.7131169, "lng": 11.990821 },

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=driving&origin=57.6668425492578,11.93603981709&destination=57.7130994553088,11.9909085683375&arrival_time=1548054000&key=*

"end_location": { "lat": 57.7130755, "lng": 11.9910161 },

Comment: It seems that the coordinates given are almost at the same location when you geocode it in the [geocoder tool](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/), may I know what will be the impact of this kind of difference in the result of your use case?